# What does VS Code's setting debug.showSubSessionsInToolBar do?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to figure out what the VS Code setting `debug.showSubSessionsInToolBar` does. I can't find any difference between setting it to `true` or `false`.

I thought it had to do with having a process spawn or exec new debuggable sub-processes, but I've tried it out and I see no difference in the debug toolbar.

Can someone who's using this feature please explain and provide a screenshot to what the toolbar looks like when this setting is turned on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the `debug.showSubSessionsInToolBar` is a setting that controls if a node cluster sub-process is shown indented and as part of the main process in the debug view's toolbar and callstack.

I've created a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OK2cdq9HXMw&list=PLVwLx67OHLu1HIbCihg3cohaM5eCarbiQ) explaining what this setting does.